# Solve the given initial value problem and determine approximately the interval of existence?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Here's the question:

Solve the given initial value problem and determine approximately the
interval of existence.
$$ (2x-y)dx+(2y-x)dy=0, \ \ y(1)=3. $$

I solved and got this:
$$ x^2-xy+y^2=7. $$

But how do I approximate the interval of existence?
Thank you !

Comment: You want to solve for $y$ and it satisfies a quadratic equation according to what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Solving for $y$ we have:$$y^2-xy+x^2-7=0$$ for domain of existence we must consider where discriminant is not negative i.e.$$4x^2-4.(x^2-7)\ge 0$$which leads to always true $28\ge 0$. So the existence domain is all $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: If by delta you meant discriminant, then it should be $b^2 - 4ac = x^2 - 4(x^2 - 7)$.

Comment: Yes that's true...

Comment: That's very kind of you!